# res.sendFile renders the HTML page, but not the related CSS/JS (node.js)

Tags: node.js

I have a .html file that is rendered through res.SendFile. It has references to some CSS and JS in other folders. I've tried using relative path, absolute path, and it still does not render. The browser says it can't find it.

The folders that contain the JS and CSS are new folders under the "public" folder. Do I need to do something else? Just wondering if it's restricting access to those files. New to node.js.

This is all on my local computer for testing.

I tried relative and absolute paths to those files, but neither worked. Out of luck

Comment: If the error is 404 for those files the problem is not access permission, more likely a problem with the way you wrote the path in the html tags, could you show the relevant part of your html code and the structure of your files tree?

Comment: It's a 404 for all of those files according to the console. So, some sample URLs here in my code. The folder structure is

public/assets/

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/fontawesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/templatemo-digimedia-v3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/animated.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/owl.css">

These CSS files exist in the /assets/css folder under "public".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your code it is difficult to say what the problem exactly is, but a common issue is that you are not setting up Express to use your `public` directory.

To serve static files properly, you can add the following code:

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Accordingly, you may create requests to your files using this format: `GET http://ip:port/directoryInPublic/file`

Additionally, you can specify a specific endpoint to serve your static content in, such as: `GET http://ip:port/static/directoryInPublic/file`.

You may do this using the following code:

```js
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

For more information, [click here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). (Official Documentation)

Comment: I am actually using app.use('/static', express.static('public')) above the part of my code that points to the HTML page below.

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('./homepage_3.html', {root: __dirname })
});

Then when the HTML page loads that's when the images don't. The content does, however. I know the CSS/image/js paths are correct because if I copy out the HTML and associated CSS/image/JS folders to another folder locally and view it, the HTML page renders fine. Is it something with the express server?

Comment: Have you had a look at your DevTools network tab and seeing whats happening with the requests?

Comment: Yes, 404 errors on all of the images, css, js.

Comment: Can  you verify that it is being queried from the correct url? Namely: `ip:port/static/css/file.css`

Comment: If I hardcode http://localhost:3000/assets/css/animated.css, for example, I get a 404. That file is in the assets/css folder under my "public" folder in my node.js app.

Comment: So the contradiction is that you are doing `app.use('/static', express.static('public'))` which uses the path `/static` however you are querying on `/assets`

Comment: I also see in the top of the console:  

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Thats an issue with your imports in your HTML file. That is out of the scope of this question. Please do mark this solution as correct .

Comment: Actually, my code is this for the static: app.use(express.static('public'));

Comment: In that case you would use `ip:port/css/file.css` instead of `ip:port/static/css/file.css`

Comment: But my post is about the browser not getting those files.

Comment: I did do that as you can see in my URL several posts above....Is there something I need to add to the app that would make those folders available?

Comment: You seem to be providing mixed answers, your path seems to change each time.
Check your global public folder handler & your paths in your html file.

Comment: The app.use was a typo. There's nothing changing. Where do I check my global public folder handler? Sorry, new to node.js

Comment: The global public folder handler is your `app.use` function which has the folder as a parameter.